# TSQL to get the list of associated users from all databases for SQl server Login

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for tsql query to get all the associated users in all dbs for a login.
Tried below SQL, but this is not giving right result set.

If I execute this query under the Database context where the user is present, it gives output as if user is present in all DBs.

Same query executed under the Database context where the user is absent, gives 0 rows as if user is not present in any of the DBs.

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'select  ''?'' AS DBName,dp.name as username from sys.database_principals dp join sys.server_principals 
srp on dp.sid=srp.sid where srp.name=''domain\account'''
```

Thanks

Comment: can you please make a [mre] s0o that we can see what you get and what you expect

Comment: Add `USE [?];` to the beginning of the script: `exec sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?];select...`.

Comment: @nbk That's a duplicate of what Learning_DBAdmin posted.

Comment: @J.D. i noticed that and voted accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Dynamic SQL to build the query you need to hit all databases and get a list of Users:

```
DECLARE @LoginName AS NVARCHAR(100) = N'Your Login Name Here'
DECLARE @DynamicSQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL +
    'SELECT ''' + [name] + ''' AS DatabaseName, [name] AS UserName FROM [' + [name] + '].sys.database_principals WHERE [type] IN (''S'', ''U'', ''E'', ''G'') AND [name] = ''' + @LoginName + ''' UNION ALL ' 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE [state] = 0; -- Online databases only

SET @DynamicSQL = LEFT(@DynamicSQL, LEN(@DynamicSQL) - 10); -- Cleans up unneeded trailing "UNION ALL"

-- PRINT @DynamicSQL -- Prints the dynamic SQL string (For Testing)
EXEC master.sys.sp_ExecuteSQL @DynamicSQL -- Executes the dynamic SQL string
```

I based it off the query Aaron Bertrand is using in the answer that @Learning_DBAdmin linked, but I figured re-writing my own Dynamic SQL could make it a little more readable. (And as he mentions sp_msforeachdb is undocumented and unreliable, so better to query dynamically.)

This can be used to get SQL Users, Windows Users, Azure Active Directory External Users, and Windows Groups based on the [Type column in sys.database_principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (you can adjust this as needed).

Comment: Note that the behavior of aggregate string concatenation (e.g. `SELECT @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL +`) is undefined. Use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` for deterministic results.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for the info, but I don't fully understand the point. Are there any issues with it being nondeterministic I might be unaware of?

Comment: I should have said "undefined". The actual behavior depends on the execution plan and can yield unexpected results.

Comment: @DanGuzman Hmm interesting, I've never seen any example of that before. Have any references or an example that reflects unexpected results? (I've been doing string concatenation like this for my dynamic SQL queries for a few years and have yet to encounter that, but it would certainly be good for me to be aware of.)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136). Unfortunately, some of the KB article and Connect feedback links are now dead but the "undefined behavior" is a quote from the SQL Server product team.

Comment: @DanGuzman From further research it seems like the "undefined" behavior is only in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause when expecting deterministic ordering of the concatenation. Also this seems like a very old issue dating back to SQL Server 2005, so not sure if that's been fixed since then. As far as any further research shows so far, I believe the query I provided above will always return the same guaranteed deterministic results. Good insight though, I'm going to continue to research into it.

Comment: This is the direct quote from Umachandar Jayachandran of the SQL Server product team from the retired connect item: “Even without ORDER BY, we do not guarantee that `@var = @var +` will produce the concatenated value for any statement that affects multiple rows. The right-hand side of the expression can be evaluated either once or multiple times during query execution and the behavior as I said is plan dependent.“. I included that quote in [this blog article](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-system-table-statistics-update/) on a separate subject to explain the queries.